# Is there a way to view comments against a question/answer that was removed?

Tags: discussion, comments, deletion

Earlier today I raised a question to enquire whether it may be possible to circumnavigate the globe over the poles by a balloon. Logging in after a few hours, the inbox widget advised there were two comments against the question. However the question is removed, and I'm at a loss to both know why and view the comments that were posted.

It is possible the comments may convey on what was wrong with the question, and why it was being removed. Is there a way to view comments now that the question is removed?

I would move that the inbox widget be modified so comments against a removed question/answer are shown as struck so the user would know not to attempt to view them.

Answer (score 2):

The comments were

> Welcome to Skeptics. What is the notable claim here? This just sounds
>   like a question out of personal curiosity. – Flimzy
>
> Ask yourself: "Which way to the major air streams go?" – dmckee

Usually we wait a bit before deleting an off-topic question, so that the author has a chance to see it was closed and any comments on it. In this case it obviously wasn't long enough.

Comment: Yep, my fault. Sorry about that... the question is now undeleted.

Comment: Thank you, both (+: